# Trying to incorporate crossdomain XML feed into jQuery app with proxy.php results in 406 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, isbn

Even just a simple `<?php readfile($_GET['url']) ?>` results in a not acceptable error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Next time, please read this before making your question community wiki http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

This just won't work because with AJAX you are restricted with the same origin policy. So unless your site is actually hosted in isbndb.com, this will never work.

From the [W3C documentation 3.6.1.13](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method)

> If the origin of url is not same origin with the XMLHttpRequest origin raise a SECURITY_ERR exception and terminate these steps.

You have to parse the data from isbndb.com on your server and then return it, you can't do cross-domain call with AJAX.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense...only now that I'm using a proxy.php script I am tripping 406 errors

Comment: If your proxy return 406 error, it may be problem in php. Check `LiveHTTPHeader` extension for valid headers in `isbndb.com` and set it with `curl` in php.

Comment: thanks.  I've given up on that idea for now though.  If you would like to take a look at what I am trying to do go here http://www.urbanvintner.co.nz/book/